# How to improve performance of extracting date and time from string in SQL Server 2008R2?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, parsing

I am working on a data migration task (SSIS), using SQL 2008 database where I have to extract the date and time from a string and convert it into a datetime data type field to be able to insert later in a table.

I do have a SQL function saved in the database which I am using in a query and it is parsing the string correctly to output the correct results. The only major problem is that the query is taking about an hour and half to get some 120,000 records. If I can be please pointed to the right direction as to if I need to correct my query or function to improve performance significantly.

The query where I am using the string parsing function (fnExtrDateTimeFromString) is

```
select
case when dbo.fnExtrDateTimeFromString(NoteList.Item) is null then CAST('2000-01-01 00:00:00.000' as datetime)
     when CAST(dbo.fnExtrDateTimeFromString(NoteList.Item) as date) = CAST('1900-01-01' as date) then dbo.fnExtrDateTimeFromString(NoteList.Item)+CAST('2000-01-01 00:00:00.000' as datetime)
     else dbo.fnExtrDateTimeFromString(NoteList.Item) end as NoteDate,
CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(NoteList.Item)) as text) as UsersNotes
from UserNotes
cross apply convDelimitedSplit(UserNotes.NoteText,',') as NoteList
where LEN(ISNULL(UserNotes.Notes,'')) > 0
```

Inside the fnExtrDateTimeFromString function, I am using 2 table variables to store all the patterns of date and time format and then using patindex to later concatenate both the string of the date & time, and concatenate to a datetime field. It is 300 something line function which I am not aware I can paste here.

An example of the string is **'User appt:7/27/94@ 10:30AM'**, and the date would be 07/27/1994 and time 10:30. These are user input strings, so they are very inconsistent regarding spaces and separating characters.
[image: Example string and output]

Comment: Please post your query plan https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: And consider the DBA site https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If I get this correctly, there is a column `UserNotes.NoteText` with a comma separated list of notes. You call `CROSS APPLY` for a splitter function. Then you use a scalar function multiple times to extract the values needed. First of all show: Please show the expensive code (the splitter and den scalar function) and Second: Please provide sample data in cosumable (copy'and'paste) format. Best was a [mcve]

Comment: This is not something that you should do in the database. This date should be parsed in the client application and sent as a different parameter into SQL server.

Comment: FYI: `text` data type is deprecated, you should use `VARCHAR( MAX )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Shnugo has pointed out you are calling this "expensive" function multiple times for each row.

To ensure only one call is made use sub-query:

```
select
    case when NoteDate is null then CAST('2000-01-01 00:00:00.000' as datetime)
        when NoteDate = CAST('1900-01-01' as date) then NoteDate + CAST('2000-01-01 00:00:00.000' as datetime)
        else NoteDate
    end as NoteDate,
    UsersNotes
from    
    ( select
        dbo.fnExtrDateTimeFromString(NoteList.Item) as NoteDate,
        CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(NoteList.Item)) as text) as UsersNotes
    from UserNotes
        cross apply convDelimitedSplit(UserNotes.NoteText,',') as NoteList
    where LEN(ISNULL(UserNotes.Notes,'')) > 0 ) as a
```

**Note:** `text` data type is deprecated, you should use VARCHAR( MAX )

Provided this date splitting function is the performance bottleneck, it should double/tripple the performance.

Good Read: https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression

Comment: Thanks @Alex and @Shnugo for pointing out the flaws in the code and the explanation of the cause of the bad performance. Putting the function calls into a sub-query has cut the run time into half of the original time and I am learning new information on how calling scalar functions in column listing and ``where`` clauses are inefficient.